# Javafx piechart not showing any data

Tags: java, javafx, pie-chart

I want to simply display some data in a pie chart using javafx.

I created a simple fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <PieChart fx:id="pieChart" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="100.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And my controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private PieChart pieChart;

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("I'm getting here.");
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new PieChart.Data("Executed", 60),
                        new PieChart.Data("Passed", 25),
                        new PieChart.Data("Fails", 15));

        pieChart.setData(pieChartData);
    }
}
```

But when I launch the application the pie chart shows nothing...

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, except that you forgot to define the controller in your FXML file :

```
fx:controller="yourController"
```

And don't forget the implementation.

Comment: strange thing is that i specified the controller in my Main with fxmlLoader.setController(myController); and the initialize method got called
but adding the controller to the FXML fixed it thanks!